# The API with ID does not include a resource with path /* having an integration LAMBDA on the ANY method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-cli, aws-serverless

.net core serverless web api
I am trying to do proxy integration with lambda and api gateway, everything is working fine with aws console

but i am facing issues with aws cli commands
i tried integrating with cli but the lambda is not properly integrated

```
aws apigateway create-resource --rest-api-id id --parent-id id --path-part {proxy+}


aws apigateway put-method --rest-api-id id --resource-id id --http-method ANY --authorization-type "NONE" 


aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id id --resource-id id --http-method ANY --type HTTP_PROXY --integration-http-method ANY --uri arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path//2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:account_id:function:helloworld/invocations 


aws lambda add-permission --function-name helloworld --action lambda:InvokeFunction --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com --source-arn arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:account_id:apiid/*/*/* --statement-id 12345678
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with your commands -

**Incorrect**

```
aws apigateway create-resource --rest-api-id id --parent-id id --path-part {proxy+}
```

**Correct**: Notice the double quotes

```
aws apigateway create-resource --rest-api-id id --parent-id id --path-part "{proxy+}"
```

**Incorrect**

```
aws apigateway put-integration \
    --rest-api-id id \
    --resource-id id \
    --http-method ANY \
    --type HTTP_PROXY \
    --integration-http-method ANY \
    --uri arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path//2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:account_id:function:helloworld/invocations
```

**Correct**

- type should be AWS_PROXY for Lambda Proxy Integrations.
- integration-http-method should always be POST for Lambda Proxy integration, even if the http method is GET or ANY or anything else.

```
aws apigateway put-integration \
    --rest-api-id id \
    --resource-id id \
    --http-method ANY \
    --type AWS_PROXY \
    --integration-http-method POST \
    --uri arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path//2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:account_id:function:helloworld/invocations
```

Comment: Did not understand at all. Website link shared does not work either